Is there any way I can change the placeholder text for the input control over the SharePoint list new form in Modern site
I have a SharePoint Modern list with default newform. The New form displays all the fields on the form with default place holder text as "Enter value here" for each single line of text field.
So, I want to change that text to something else. Please let me know how to do that.
Thanks in advance!

You could achieve this through Power Apps.
1.In the SharePoint list -> Integrate -> Power Apps -> Customize forms.
2.Choose the column in the left navigation -> Datecardvalue -> Advanced -> Unlock to change properties -> HintText -> "Your customized placeholder".
3.Save and publish the form to SharePoint.


Thanks. You are correct!. But, I am looking if we can do the same from default List form using json formatting within the Body section.

Per my test, it is not possible to do the same by using json formatting.
